# Почему Visual Studio 2015 не может запустить exe файл (ucrtbased.dll)?

Tags: visual-studio, exe, visual-studio-2015

Я установил Visual Studio 2015 и создал Win32 проект с неким кодом. Компиляция прошла успешно, но я не могу запустить exe файл - у меня нет какой-то библиотеки ucrtbased.dll...Как мне решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где и как вы запускаете файл? Ну и есть вероятность что статическая линковка вам поможет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов сразу же после компиляции. Если построить, потом найти exe файл и попробовать запустить - точно такая же ошибка. Я было перед этим устанавливал какие-то модули к студии (не было там возможности создавать Win32 проекты), возможно не все установилось. Можно как-то в студии проанализировать и отдельно докачать нужные файлы? Я просто с этой IDE не очень знаком.

Comment: И все же ГДЕ и КАК вы его запускаете? Из проводника, из студии? На какой машине?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов из студии, пробовал из проводника тоже - одинаковый результат. Стоит Win10 x64 и студия 32-битная. Аналогичные параметры на ноуте и та же студия, но там все работает без проблем.

Comment: Соберите релизную сборку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена переустановкой Visual Studio 2015. Видимо какой-то компонент нормально не установился.