# Не работает проект на VS17

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, скачал сегодня кандидат-версию Visual Studio 17 Pro. Ну решил посмотреть что да как. Начал с самого стандартного, дабы проверить работает ли IDE вообще, оказалось - нет. При компиляции базового "Hello World" выдаёт ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гугле решение проблемы не нашел, 3 раза делал "восстановление" и перезапускал ПК. В чём проблема?

Comment: а что находится в разделе внешние зависимости?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman https://pp.vk.me/c637219/v637219792/2463f/3Z9MKgmFa7A.jpg

Comment: А что в логе компиляции?

Comment: @VladD MSBUILD : error MSB4166: произошел преждевременный выход дочернего узла "2". Выполняется завершение работы. Диагностические данные можно найти в файлах с именем MSBuild_*.failure.txt каталога временных файлов.

Comment: @nait123321: Окей, а что в этих файлах?

Comment: @VladD хз где этот файл, пустил поиск в диске С(ОС) и F(Где установлена VS), так же в папке проекта.

Comment: Вообщем психанул и удалил эту дрисню, подожду релиз. Жаль только что VS15 прийдеться заново устанавливать...

Comment: А установка у Вас без проблем прошла? У меня ругался несколько раз по-всякому. В итоге helloworld собрался, но не запустился. Ошибка как [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/466948/176217).